# Get matrix size from a pointer- MEX

Tags: c++, matlab, size, mex

I read the second variable in C++

```
#define D prhs[1]

double* d = mxGetPr(D); // get the pointer
```

Now I want to get the size of `D`

```
int mySize = mxGetM(D);
```

cool...Now how can I get the size from the pointer `d` (not `D`)?

```
int mySize = mxGetM((const mxArray) d); // does not work
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I guess it's not possible to find the size of an array  given its pointer and mex.h also cannot do that.

Comment: How does this answer your own question? Do you know it is impossible?